# Can I randomize a list in Python using percentage?

Tags: python, arrays, list, random

Recently I've been working on a project where I need to put characters in random order with a limit, for example, if I have a list with 25,000 `"_"` in it, I need to set 4% (1,000) of these `"_"` into `"X"` in random positions.

The list that I'm working with is a bidimensional array.

Comment: Does the number of `"X"`s in the output need to be exactly 1000 (i.e. exactly 4%)? If this does not need to be exact, you can interpret 4% as a 4% probability that you will swap an `_` with an `X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a list with the required number of each character. Then use `random.shuffle()` to randomize it.

```
import random

l = 1000 * ["X"] + 24000 * ["_"]
random.shuffle(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the others have misinterpreted the question, you can use np.random.choice to get sample idxs of the char you need. For example you could write something like

```
char_idxs = np.where(ARR == interested_char)
if len(char_idxs) > max_length:
    difference = len(char_idxs) - max_length
    replace_idxs = np.random.choice(char_idxs,size=difference)
ARR[replace_idxs] = X
```